# Google hangout url returning 404

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I have a hangout app that was made public about a month ago. Since yesterday launching the app has stopped working  -- whenever I try to redirect the user to the hangout, it is followed by a 404 response. The same happens when I click on the the hangout link directly under developers console (https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts?gid=< MY_ID >). I can't find any api changes or other clues that would point to the cause of the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya I faced the same problem. I sorted it out by using the following url format

```
https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/?gid=<Your_ID>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick. It is fairly absurd that the google dev console itself uses the "old" url format, nice work figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found that google changed this to https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_?authuser=0&gid=

Look here - https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=1033